# Always use https for domain?

Tags: ssl, amazon-web-services, nginx, amazon-ec2

I have just set up a server on ec2, ubuntu with nginx and an ssl certificate through namecheap (who also provide my domain).

When I hit https://example.com the certificate comes up.

How can I make it so that if a user were to hit www.example.com or http://example.com that they use the https:// connection?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the following should work:

```
server {
  server_name example.com;
  listen 443 ssl default_server;
  # your https-specific config 
}

server {
  server_name example.com;
  listen 80;
  location / {
    return 301 https://example.com$request_uri;
  }
}
```